# Too many values to unpack error in calendar library

Tags: python, calendar

I am trying to solve 'too many values to unpack' error.
This code tries to print month name according to leap years and numbers of ends of the months. 
I want 'x,y in i,j' to give Month name according to numbers of end of the months.

```
import calendar
year=2000
a=calendar.isleap(year)
if a ==False :
    print('this is not a leap year')
    x=[0,31,59,90,120]
    y=[31,59,90,120,151]

    for i,j in zip(x, y):
                        if (i,j) == (0,31):
                            (i,j)=str('Jan')
                        if (i,j) == (31,59):
                            (i,j)=str('Feb')
                        if (i,j)==(59,90):
                            (i,j)=str('March')
                        if (i,j)==(90,120):
                            (i,j)=str('Apr')
                        if (i,j)==(120,151):
                            (i,j)=str('May')

                            print('Mont_'+ (x,y))

else: 
    print ('This is a leap year')
    x=[0,31,60,91,121,152]
    y=[31,60,91,121,152,182]
    for i,j in zip(x, y):
                        if (i,j) == (0,31):
                            (i,j)=str('Jan')
                        if (i,j) == (31,60):
                            (i,j)=str('Feb')
                        if (i,j)==(60,91):
                            (i,j)=str('March')
                        if (i,j)==(91,121):
                            (i,j)=str('Apr')
                        if (i,j)==(121,152):
                            (i,j)=str('May')
                        if (i,j)==(152,182):
                            (i,j)=str('Jun')
                            print('Mont_'+ (x,y))
```

Comment: You should add the stack trace to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error(s) are occurring when you use anything like `(i,j)=str('Jan')`. What you are asking when you assign multiple variables at once is "split the contents of my list/tuple/**string** into the variables v1, v2, v3, ..., vn, in that order". Specifically, this case, you are asking Python to split a string of 3 characters (e.g. `'Jan'` into two variables). Python has no idea how to deal with this.

From looking at your code, I think you actually want something like this:

```
print ('This is a leap year')
x=[0,31,60,91,121,152]
y=[31,60,91,121,152,182]
for i,j in zip(x, y):
    if i,j == 0,31:            # The parenthesis aren't necessary> Python implicitly converts this to a tuple
        month='Jan'            # Same with the string. No need to explicitly declare it a string - Python is very clever :)
    elif (i,j) == (31,60):
        month='Feb'
    elif (i,j)==(60,91):
        month='Mar'
    elif (i,j)==(91,121):
        month='Apr'
    elif (i,j)==(121,152):
        month='May'
    elif (i,j)==(152,182):
        month='Jun'
    else:
        month='n/a'

    print('Mont_'+ month)
```

Also note the use of `elif` after the first `if`. While in this case your results will be the same, using `elif` acts as a binding agent to group the whole block together.

Take the following example

```
a = 'string'
if a == 'string':
    a = some_function()
if a == 'int':
    a = some_other_function()
```

If, for some reason, `some_function()` returns the value `'int'`, then after this code block, `a` will have the return value of `some_other_function()`. Using `elif` here guards against both `some_function()` and `some_other_function()` being called.